# Can not connect to pgAdmin server in windows 10

Tags: postgresql

Sorry for the same repeated question but pgAdmin failed to connect to the pgAdmin application server. it will save much time from others

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that I had applied.

Simply delete C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\ and then install pgAdmin 4